# dependency Kestrel.Https 1.0.0-rc1-final does not support framework DNXCore, Version=v5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to configure https to my Kestrel server to work on **Ubuntu 14** with **dnxcore50**.

But when I add a dependency to:

> "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Https": "1.0.0-rc1-final"

And I try to restore my package I get this message:

> Dependency Kestrel.Https 1.0.0-rc1-final does not support framework DNXCore, Version=v5.0

If I go to windows and use dnx451 and add the same dependency things works great.

But, if I can't use **Kestrel.Https** on **Ubuntu** with **dnxcore50**, how can I configure Https on **Ubuntu** using **dnxcore50**?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the HTTPS version of Kestrel only targets the full .NET framework on RC1: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Https/1.0.0-rc1-final.

As of RC2 Kestrel.Https will target `netstandard1.3`: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https/project.json#L20.

So the solution is to either wait for RC2 to drop or use the bleeding RC2 bits from MyGet.

Answer (score -1):

Today Kestrel already supports HTTPS:

Here's the library tha supports it since version 1.0.0:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https/

To implement it on your code, in you main to initialize your asp.net core app add `UseHttps` as an option

Here's a sample on how to do it!

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                // options.ThreadCount = 4;
                options.NoDelay = true;
                options.UseHttps("testCert.pfx", "testPassword");
                options.UseConnectionLogging();
            })
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:5000", "https://localhost:5001")
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        // The following section should be used to demo sockets
        //var addresses = application.GetAddresses();
        //addresses.Clear();
        //addresses.Add("http://unix:/tmp/kestrel-test.sock");

        host.Run();
    }
```

Below there is also a link from the sample

https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/dev/samples/SampleApp/Startup.cs#L37-L43

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Well sad  @FelixSFD

Comment: I just added the code to improve the answer, is now better to understand?